# PowerShell PSWorkflowJob Maximum Running Instances

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm looking to get some input, confirmation, and hopefully a workaround for the following.

I'm attempting to run over 100+ PowerShell workflows within a single console. However, it appears that I can't run more than 30 jobs at the same time. This doesn't seem to be code related as executing a simple workflow with nothing but a Start-Sleep would not run more than 30. The rest of the jobs will be in a NotStarted state. As soon as you stop or suspend one of the running jobs, the proceeding jobs would then begin to run but no more than 30.

I can't seem to find any documentation that states any sort of limitation regarding this. Is this a configuration issue or limitation? Any way to workaround this aside from having multiple PowerShell consoles.

Any input?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell will throttle the number of shells created to handle workflows.  I think the two relevant values are:

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxShellsPerUser
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell.workflow\Quotas\MaxShellsPerUser
```

To set the values do this:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxShellsPerUser -Value 50
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell.workflow\Quotas\MaxShellsPerUser -Value 50
```

Comment: Sorry. Spoke to soon.

These are currently set to 100, however, when executing the workflows, via resume-job, this stops after 30 still. 

Note: Currently using PowerShell v4.

Comment: Here is a link for MaxShellsPerUser which says the default limit is 30 - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367(VS.85).aspx